# FAQ updated - need feedback

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

I've updated the first section of the [FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq). I hope that some clarity there will reduce the number of off-topic questions we've been getting.

I welcome any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: I know that we've articulated the information elsewhere on AE, in comments and on meta, but I haven't been able to find anything to use so far. If you know of some good stuff, point me in the right direction.

Comment: Very good.  I've noticed a substantial uptick in bad questions myself.  I think you've covered most of it but I'll make sure to add anything I notice in the future.  **Edit:** I lied, I made a couple additions.

Comment: Looks good.  I agree with legal one, but we technically do cover that fact in rooting (voiding warranty)

Comment: @BryanDenny: Sure, but it's fairly clear that "Is rooting legal?" is off-topic, while "How do I root...?" is on-topic. Although, frankly, I think rooting is so big and yet so specialized that we're not a good resource for such questions (the omnibus question about rooting excepted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some other posts on meta which have helped:

- [FAQ: "What kind of questions should I ask here?"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-ask-here)
- [FAQ: "What kind of questions should I NOT ask here?"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-not-ask-here)
- [Are questions looking for apps on topic? As in: "I need an app that does XYZ?" or "I want a widget that does ABC"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353/are-questions-looking-for-apps-on-topic-as-in-i-need-an-app-that-does-xyz-o)
- [Are app recommendations still considered off-topic?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/494/are-app-recommendations-still-considered-off-topic)
- [Should the FAQ section on off-topic questions be clarified?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/529/should-the-faq-section-on-off-topic-questions-be-clarified)
- [Can the FAQ be expanded in terms of what's on topic?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/589/can-the-faq-be-expanded-in-terms-of-whats-on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

**I like it :-)**

Maybe you could change

```
Professional and enthusiast programmers, ask on Stack Overflow.
```

to

```
Professional and enthusiast Android programmers, ask on Stack Overflow.
```

under *What kind of questions should I not ask here?*

Comment: That portion of the FAQ is not editable by Moderators. In fact, it's boilerplate on all of the Stack Exchange sites. That particular line comes from the fact that Stack Overflow is one of the pre-defined migration paths, and that's the description that's used. (If/when other migration paths are added, they would be similar added to that section.)